# MySQL - Getting differences between two sets of data on two table using join?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Assuming that I have multiple sets of reports from multiple individuals. How do I identify the changes between these datas and decide which to merge to a specific database.

Scenario where applicable

- When data exist in Data 1 but not Data 2
- When data exist in Data 2 but not Data 1
- When data does not match in both table (whether it's sales/revenue) and assuming there are more columns than just revenue that might have different values

**Data 1**

```
Date        Sales   Revenue
2016-01-01  27      30
2016-01-03  12      10
2016-01-04  48      50
```

**Data 2**

```
Date        Sales   Revenue
2016-01-01  27      10
2016-01-02  31      40
2016-01-04  48      50
```

**Desired Outcome**

```
Date        Sales   T1 Revenue  T2 Revenue
2016-01-01  27      30          10
2016-01-02  31      NULL        40
2016-01-03  12      10          NULL
2016-01-04  48      50          50
```

I have tried various method including a combination of UNION and JOIN, nothing seem to work for me right now.

The closest I got right now is the following.

```
SELECT d1.date,
       d1.sales,
       d1.revenue AS T1,
       d2.revenue AS T2

FROM dataset1 d1

RIGHT JOIN dataset2 d2 ON d1.date = d2.date

WHERE d1.revenue <> d2.revenue
OR (d1.revenue IS NOT NULL AND d2.revenue IS NULL)
OR (d1.revenue IS NULL AND d2.revenue IS NOT NULL)
```

The jump between left join / right join will only work depending on which side has the missing data.

Searched the site but haven't found a solution working for me =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `full join`.

```
SELECT coalesce(d1.date,d2.date) dt,
       coalesce(d1.sales,d2.sales) sales,
       d1.revenue AS T1Revenue,
       d2.revenue AS T2Revenue
FROM dataset1 d1
FULL JOIN dataset2 d2 ON d1.date = d2.date
```

Use `coalesce` to get the non-null value for a column when it is not present in either of the given tables.

As MySQL doesn't support `full join`, this can be done with a combination of `left` and `right` joins with a `union` combining the results.

```
SELECT d1.date dt,
       d1.sales sales,
       d1.revenue AS T1Revenue,
       d2.revenue AS T2Revenue
FROM dataset1 d1
LEFT JOIN dataset2 d2 ON d1.date = d2.date
UNION
SELECT d2.date dt,
       d2.sales sales,
       d1.revenue AS T1Revenue,
       d2.revenue AS T2Revenue
FROM dataset1 d1
RIGHT JOIN dataset2 d2 ON d1.date = d2.date
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: MySQL does not support full join.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I don't think you need the grouping or aggregate functions if you take out the `ALL` from `UNION ALL`.

Comment: This is working for me. I didn't think about using Union to combine a left join and right join query earlier. It does seem like a large query. Is this the most efficient way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Turn out I was wrong. It doesn't work. Check my update above.

Comment: @Ken Does it work or doesn't it? What update? What's the problem?

Comment: My mistake actually. Since my query require some complex selection / conditioning. I messed up thinking that it didn't work. This is now selected as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.*
     , d1.revenue t1_revenue
     , d2.revenue t2_revenue
  FROM (SELECT date, sales FROM data1
         UNION
        SELECT date, sales FROM data2
       ) x
  LEFT
  JOIN data1 d1
    ON d1.date = x.date
  LEFT
  JOIN data2 d2
    ON d2.date = x.date
 ORDER
    BY date;
```

Comment: Works for me but must add WHERE clause for NULL value on either side

      WHERE
        (d1.revenue <> d2.revenue)
        OR (d1.revenue IS NULL AND d2.revenue IS NOT NULL)
        OR (d1.revenue IS NOT NULL AND d2.revenue IS NULL)
     ORDER
        BY date;

Comment: I don't follow. If you want an INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN, then use an INNER JOIN!

Comment: Sorry Strawberry. This is working solution but I feel that vkp's method above are more readable and seems like a shorter query! Nevertheless its a good alternative.

Comment: I would be (very slightly) surprised if an alternative method is faster, but please use whatever method with which you're comfortable.

Comment: I'll look up and compare the query time. Thank for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

One method is brute force:

```
select 'd1' as which, d1.*
from data1 d1
where not exists (select 1
                  from data2 d2
                  where d1.date = d2.date and d1.revenue <=> d2.revenue
                 )
union all
select 'd2' as which, d2.*
from data1 d2
where not exists (select 1
                  from data1 d1
                  where d1.date = d2.date and d1.revenue <=> d2.revenue
                 );
```

Your sample query only compares `revenue`, but you can use the same logic to compare `sales`.  Note that `<=>` is the `NULL`-safe comparison operator.

Comment: This does get me a full list but the differences are listed in separate rows. The trouble listing each date entry on the same row while their differences is listed within separate columns.