# SQL server: Difference between columns based on other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

[image: https://image.ibb.co/jvB6Tw/Capture.png]

I need to find difference in SQL between revenues of 2016 and 2017, based on a 3 columns: month year, unique ID.

```
=D16-INDEX($D$2:$D$100,INDEX(MATCH(A16&B16&C16-1,$A$2:$A$100&$B$2:$B$100&$C$2:$C$100,0),,))
```

here is excels working Formula.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Excel? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Or, even worse, links to images.)

Comment: Duplicate question [answer][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064511/mysql-getting-differences-between-two-sets-of-data-on-two-table-using-join

Comment: MySQL. So i added link because it would be easier to show what i mean.so in first column i have unique ID, in second column i have month in third i have year in 4th i have revenues. so i need difference between 2016 and 2017 years of revenues where ID and month matches. (this is my first time i use stackoverflow )